# SQL Server Linux admin tools

Tags: linux, sql-server, sql-management-studio

I would like to know if there is sql server tools for linux?

eg. tools like sql server enterprise manager.

Comment: What database server do you need to manage?

Comment: mssql server (sql server). Version 2000 or more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a lot of good reasons, there aren't any tools for Linux that match the functionality of SSMS. If you need something like that, run a slim Windows VM on your Linux machine and use the real deal.

In addition to SQuirrel Universal SQL Client, you can also try Oracle's free app:

Oracle SQL Developer
http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/database/sql_developer/index.html

Like SQuirrel, it's written and Java and depends on the jTDS JDBC driver. Which probably means that it has the same set of limitations.  Same goes for tools that are connecting throug ODBC- SSMS connects directly to SQL Server and can do a lot of things that a generic JDBC/ODBC tool simply won't do.

Answer (score 2):

There is a new tool from Microsoft, [Sql Operations Studio](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-operations-studio/download).

Visual Studio like interface, similar SSMS functionality. You can install it on Windows, Mac AND LINUX (deb and rpm packages)

Answer (score 1):

[SQuirrel SQL client:](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/)